# How to replace an empty variable of searchPhrase?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem. I have features to sort, filter and search and when textarea of searchPhrase is null I have a problem:

```
Error: error https://localhost/cases/caselistsorted/no-filter/search_customer//casetype/desc
```

And I can't use sort and filter when searchPhrase is null.
How I can fix it?

This is my code:

```
           function sendParam(element) {
            var filterSelect = $("#filterSelect").val();
            var searchOption = $("#searchOption").val();
            var searchPhrase = $("#searchPhrase").val();
            var params1 = $(element).attr("sort");
            var params2 = $(element).attr("order");
            var url = "{{restUrl}}cases/caselistsorted/" + filterSelect 
                      + "/" + searchOption + "/"+searchPhrase + "/" 
                      + params1 + "/" + params2;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: null,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        console.log(url);
                        $(".case-list").html(data["code"]);
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error: " + textStatus + " " + url);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).on('ready', function(){
            $('.button-sort').on('click', function() {
                sendParam(this);
            });
            $('#filterSelect').change(function () {
                sendParam(this);
            });
        });

        function customerSearch() {
        sendParam(this);
        }

        function customerSearchTextInput(event) {
            if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
                customerSearch();
                return false;
            } else if (event.which == 27 || event.keyCode == 27) {
                customerSearchClear();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function customerSearchClear() {
            var searchPhrase = $("#searchPhrase").val("");
            console.log("FieldClear!");
        }
```

When I write in searchPhrase somethink e.g "hello" I have such an outcome:

```
"https://localhost/cases/caselistsorted/no-filter/search_customer/hello/createDate/asc"
```

PHP Code :

```
if ($filter && $searchOption && $searchPhrase && $sortField == "createDate" && $order == "asc") {
            usort($caseList, function ($a, $b) {
                /* @var $a CMCase */
                /* @var $b CMCase */
                $time1 = strtotime($a->createDate);
                $time2 = strtotime($b->createDate);
                return $time1 > $time2;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if `searchPhrase` is not null by adding a ternary

```
(searchPhrase ? "/" + searchPhrase : "")
```

and only add the `/` (and searchPhrase) if it holds a value:

```
var url = "{{restUrl}}cases/caselistsorted/" + filterSelect 
           + "/" + searchOption + (searchPhrase ? "/" + searchPhrase : "") 
           + "/" + params1 + "/" + params2;
```

Comment: Thank you it's work but what I need here to change the sorting work in php code. Look in my code I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use arrays, you can try something like this.

Note, its better to have a dataStructure, an object or an array. Object will not have order, so either you will have to use map or if you are on ES6, use set

```js
var data = [];
/*data.push($("#filterSelect").val());
data.push($("#searchOption").val());
data.push($("#searchPhrase").val());
data.push($(element).attr("sort"));
data.push($(element).attr("order"));*/

data.push("test");
data.push("");
data.push("Hello");
data.push("World");
data.push("");


function isNotEmpty(val){
  return !(
    val === undefined ||
    val === null ||
    val.toString().trim().length === 0
  )
}

var qsString = data.filter(isNotEmpty).join("/");
console.log(qsString)
```